# Delete a particular IMarker in builder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am currently into `Eclipse` plugin development. I am in the need of using `IMarker` for a custom builder. I am creating project marker through `org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker` and I am using `IMarker.PROBLEM` for two different situations.

How to delete and refresh a particular `IMarker` without deleting all the `iMarker` in the project resource.

I tried `delete()` method in the `IMarker` implementation. But it is not helping me out. And I found only the method `deleteMarkers()` in the project that actually deletes all the markers that are available in the project resource.

```
iProject.deleteMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true,
                    IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE);
iProject.refreshLocal(IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
```

Please help me through this, I want to delete only a particular `IMarker` at the specified situation. I could not delete individual markers. Are there any source or reference you can point me to ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have either store or find your specific markers. You can look for a marker in a selected resource (not on a project, but the current resource):

```java
IMarker[] problems = null;
int depth = IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE;
try {
   problems = resource.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, depth);
} catch (CoreException e) {
   // something went wrong
}
```

When you have the correct marker, you can 1) update it by setting its properties, or 2) delete it using IMarker.delete().

The code snippet used here comes from the [Mark My Words tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html).